# Creating a simple setup where I can design with live updates/reloads of my browser

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

So far I have setup a very basic setup using npm:

```
npm init
node install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3
```

So my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "n2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
  }
}
```

I see nodemon is used, but from what I understand this won't automatically reload my browser when I make a change correct?

Do I need to create a index.js file and have nodejs code in it?

Answer (score 1):

Node assumes the main file listed in package.json file of the directory as the entry point. It's up to you where you put your code just use the right filename while running it. I will assume your code to be in server.js

For using nodemon you will need to install it either globally or as devDependency. Once that is done you can configure your package.json.

Refer to [this](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) page installation and usage section for updated documentation on using nodemon.

```
{
    "name": "n2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon ./server.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3"
    }
}
```

Then you can simply run the following command to run your server.

```
$ npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you use [livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload) to reload the page on file change.

#### Example

Install livereload globally:

```
npm install -g livereload
```

Add this script to your index.html:

```
<script>
  document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] +
  ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')
</script>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Now if you run the livereload command in the app folder, the page will refresh whenever a file is changed.